# What happens to the commits that are not shared/mutual among multiple branches and you rebase one of the branch?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-rebase

My git structure looks like this

```
    M1 -- M2 -- M3 -- ..................... -- M70
           \                                   /
(branch P)  P1 -- P2 -- P3 -- P4 -- P5        /(branch rebase on M70)
                         \(tag and branch)   /
(branch C)               C1 -- C2 -- C3 -- C4
```

In the above diagram, I have `M` as pushed changes in master branch by different people. `Branch P` and `branch C` are my branches and code changes.

I worked from `P1 to P5`. Later I realized a need of branch on top of commit `P3`, so I **tagged** the `commit P3` and created a branch on top of the tag and worked from commmits `C1 to C4`. Now I want to rebase and in future merge `P1, P2, P3, C1, C2, C3, C4` commits. Since commits `P1, P2, P3` are shared in both branches what will happen to `branch P` as these shared commits will be rebased on M70 (I guess)? Will `branch P` retain a copy of the shared commits or will commits `P4` and `P5` become orphaned?

There is a possibility that I want to in future work on `branch P` and merge that to master when work on `branch C` is complete.

*Note - I haven't done the rebase of C4 on M70 yet.*

Comment: A branch in Git is basically just a pointer to a certain commit.  Branch P should still point to the same commit after the rebase.

Comment: Do you mean point to commit M2 or to commit P3?

Comment: Please give us the _actual command_ you are thinking of giving.

Comment: I will be using git extensions instead of command. And my steps will be 
1. git checkout branch
2. git fetch all
2. git rebase on master with selected commit interactively where I will pick all commits from P1 to C4
3. git push force with lease to push into remote branch from local

In the end if my integration  build is success then I will merge it to master.

Answer (score 0):

Rebasing C on Master will not impact Branch P.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).